# How to dynamically change the spacing between two DIVs depending on if the top DIV is present or removed?

Tags: css, sass

I have two DIV elements. I will call them `DIV A` and `DIV B`. I am creating a space between the two `DIVs`  of 20px. Example `margin-top: 20px`.  Here is a diagram to show that.
[image: diagram]
Let's say if `DIV A` is not present in the page, or is removed. In that case,  I don't want to have 20px spacing from `DIV B`  to it's parent `DIV`. I just want to use whatever the default spacing is.

I am wondering if there is a way to automatically change spacing for this scenario using CSS?

Comment: `div.a + div.b { margin-top: 20px; }`, this will select `div.b` only when it's right after `div.a` and if they both have the same parent. It's called adjacent sibling selector.

Answer (score 1):

Use `margin-bottom: 20px` on div A. In this way, if div A is not present the 20px spacing will also not be present.

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: flex;` + `flex-direction: column` on the container. Then you can create the spacing by adding the `gap` property:

```js
// for demonstration purpose only 
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('#A').style.display = 'none';
})
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 20px;
}


/* for visualization purpose only */
div {
  border: 2px dashed red;
  min-height: 30vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="A">A <button>Remove DIV</button></div>
<div id="B">B</div>
```

Alternatively you could use a combination of CSS-Selectors:

```js
// for demonstration purpose only 
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('#A').style.display = 'none';
})
```

```css
div:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

/* for visualization purpose only */
div {
  border: 2px dashed red;
  min-height: 30vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="A">A <button>Remove DIV</button></div>
<div id="B">B</div>
```

Comment: Very easy to do in css flex:

    `<div class="content">
    <div class="content_child">Hello world</div>
  <div class="content_child">Hello world</div>
</div>

    .content {display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;}
.content .content_child {
      flex: 1 0 0%;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background:#333;
  color:white;
}
`

Comment: flex-wrap will not sustain the default block-level behavior but might places elements next to each other. Changing the flex-direction will maintain that and is less effort while also bein less nasty to fix. In general you should not overwrite all default behaviors with very specific declerations that also will overwrite wanted default behavior.